# ORA-29902: error in executing ODCIIndexStart() routine ORA-20000: Oracle Text error: DRG-50901: text query parser syntax error on line 1, column 19

Tags: oracle, text

```
SELECT person_no sub_sys_individual_id,
 nm_e,
 nm_a,
 nvl(sex, -1) sex,
nvl(prs_nat, -999) prs_nat,
person_no,
'NA' prog_where_not_allowed,
'NA' udb_no,
 person_tp,
 pass_no
FROM ban_inq_tab
WHERE contains (nm_e ,'xxstart JUHETI BT MEMED ASMANI%') >0
AND (trans_flag IS NULL OR trans_flag = 'C');
```

please help me in this issue and getting parser syntax error

Comment: Does the query work without this: `WHERE contains (nm_e ,'xxstart JUHETI BT MEMED ASMANI%') >0`

Comment: yes  query is working fine without contains. Help me in handling this reseved word BT

Comment: Its look like OracleText index error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, you'll also get this error (i'm on Oracle 12.2) if you have the input parameter to a stored proc that will be the query in a contains predicate as an NVARCHAR2.
So if you have input params to a stored proc as NVARCHAR2 and that parameter is destined for the query in the contains predicate, then change it to VARCHAR (or maybe CLOB) and it will no longer throw this error.

Answer (score 2):

You must escape the BT special word (but you can just escape the entire string).

```
SELECT person_no sub_sys_individual_id,
 nm_e,
 nm_a,
 nvl(sex, -1) sex,
nvl(prs_nat, -999) prs_nat,
person_no,
'NA' prog_where_not_allowed,
'NA' udb_no,
 person_tp,
 pass_no
FROM ban_inq_tab
WHERE contains (nm_e ,'{xxstart JUHETI BT MEMED ASMANI}%') >0
AND (trans_flag IS NULL OR trans_flag = 'C');
```

Comment: If we add { } means its not returning result. Am getting not getting issue if i use BT in start or end. Its throwing error only we uses BT in mid word. Is there any way to use BT in stoplist or stopword to prevent this.

Comment: Possibly try concatenating it? `WHERE contains (nm_e ,'xxstart JUHETI ' || '/BT' || ' MEMED ASMANI%') >0`

Comment: i have scenario if the words were BT,SYN etc in need to escape them with /BT,/SYN. How to achieve this with regexp_replace  SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('JUHETI BT MEMA', 'BT', '\BT',2) FROM dual;             How to use list of words in this  regexp_replace function

Answer (score 0):

The error is causing the BT, which is a reserved word. The solution is described in the [Oracle Community forum](https://community.oracle.com/message/10317459).

Comment: Thanks Mike, In that post they mentioned that putting curly braces {} will solve the issue. But for me now after putting {} no rows returned from the query.

Comment: Help me in handling this reserved word BT

Comment: Try to replace the reserved word BT (Broader Term) with the escape character /. Your search string would be like <pre>where contains (oratext ,'xxstart JUHETI /BT MEMED ASMANI%') >0<code> . Also You can read more on the oracle documentation on the [oracle text contains query operator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24436/cqoper.htm#CCREF0300)