# Oracle Text bind variable in CONTAINS function. How to deal with null values?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, oracle-apex-5, oracle-text

I'm developing an application on Oracle Apex with Full Text search on table by Oracle Text.  Application has a query like this:

```
select task_id, ...
from vhd_tasks 
where contains(hw_sn, :P5)>0
```

In this case text index works fine, if :P5 is not null because it uses domain index

```
|  60 |                         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| HD_TASKS          |  1257 |   326K|   322   (0)| 00:00:04 |
|* 61 |                          DOMAIN INDEX              | CTX_HD_TASKS      |       |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
```

But I don't know how to change my query to deal with null in :P5
when search string is not populated in :P5.
I had try this query

```
select task_id, ...
from vhd_tasks 
where ( case when :P5 is not null then  contains(hw_sn, :P5, 1)
       else 1 end)>0
```

Unfortunatly performance decreases dramatically in this case.
Any idea how to deal with null value in CONTAINS function?

Comment: Can be :P5 like this '%WER' another words: are you using regular expr in bind value?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is `union all`:

```
select task_id, ...
from vhd_tasks 
where contains(hw_sn, :P5) > 0
union all
select . . .
from vhd_tasks
where :P5 is null;
```

You can also see if Oracle would optimize the `where` clause using:

```
where :P5 is null or contains(hw_sn, :P5, 1) > 0
```

The optimizer will not understand `case`, but it might work better with `or`.

Comment: Union all doesn't work oracle throws error [Error] Execution (101: 1): ORA-29902: error in ODCIIndexStart()
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-50901: text query parser syntax error on line 1, column 1

Comment: @Виктор Шапошников You can't use null or empty strigs in contains. I wonder who your problem query(the first one) works if you put in :P5 null? It also should get the same error.

Comment: @EvgeniyK. You're right I can't use my first query in application as it doesn't except null value but second query has unexceptable performance.

Comment: You can probably use `coalesce(:P5, ' ')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It is some modification example of Gordon Linoff example

```
select *
from Oracle_text 
where :P5 is not null and contains(object_name, :P5)>0
union all
select *
from Oracle_text 
where :P5 is null and object_name is null
```

But be carefull. Look at this [ORA-29902: error in executing ODCIIndexStart() routine ORA-20000: Oracle Text error: DRG-50901: text query parser syntax error on line 1, column 19](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26757387/ora-29902-error-in-executing-odciindexstart-routine-ora-20000-oracle-text-er)

If you use `exec :P5 = 'PB'` then your get error ORA-29902.
All reserved words here(https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/text.102/b14218/cqspcl.htm).
Then you can escape entire string like this.(Also note in link)

```
select task_id, ...
from vhd_tasks 
where contains(hw_sn, '{' || :P5 || '}') > 0
```

But it wouldn't search codition like this `'%DUAL'`